# Unable to insert data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbee to CodeIgniter and PHP. I am trying to insert data using a form and display it on the same view page using MVC pattern given by CodeIgniter. My View is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

 <? echo form_open('books/input'); ?>

 <? echo $id; ?>: 

<? echo form_input('id'); ?>

</br>

<? echo $title; ?>: 

<? echo form_input('title'); ?>

</br>

<? echo $body; ?>: 

<? echo form_input('body'); ?>

</br>



<? echo form_submit('mysubmit','Submit!');  ?>

<? echo form_close(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and My Controller is:

```
<? class Books extends Controller{

    function Books(){

        parent::Controller();
    }

    function main(){

        $this->load->model('books_model');
        $data = $this->books_model->general();
        //$this->load->view('books_main',$data);
    }

    function input(){

        $this->load->helper('form');  

        $this->load->model('books_model');

        $data = $this->books_model->general();
        $this->load->view('books_input',$data);   
    }

} ?>
```

and My model is just returning the data entered by the user as:

```
<? class books_model extends Model{

    function books_model(){
        $this->load->helper('url');               
    }

    function general(){

        $data['id']      = 'id';
        $data['title']      = 'title';
        $data['body']     = 'body';

        return $data;   
    }
} ?>
```

But when I try to access the form, it shows me an error quoting:

```
    load->model('books_model'); $data = $this->books_model->general();  } 
function input(){ $this->load->helper('form'); $this->load->model('books_model'); $data = $this->books_model->general();
 $this->load->view('books_input',$data); } } ?>
     404 Page Not Found
```

though I am accessing it with the same URL: localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/input

How can I access this form and insert data successfully?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @Vinod, I have written there buddy. In the error message, it is showing the contents of my Controller.

Comment: Have you tried changing the short php (`<? ?>`) tags  to normal php (`<?php ?>`) tags? It looks to me that Short Open PHP Tags option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Every Class name should start with capital letter
like

```
class Books_model extends Model
```

and do type like this

```
$this->load->model('Books_model');
```

this could be the issue that you are getting "404 page not found".

Read some basic things that you have to follow from guide
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html